# copy files remotely on same path

Tags: command-line, rsync, scp

I have thousands of csv files in some directories. Out of which I would like to copy one csv file to remote machine on same path, if remote machine doesn't have directory then it should create directory and copy it to that path.

Let me elaborate with example, say I have file called `foo.csv` in some directories

```
test/
├── 201512
    └── foo.csv
    └── bar.csv
├── 201601
    └── foo.csv
    └── abc.csv 
├── 201602
    └── foo.csv
    └── xyz.csv
.
.
├── 201612
    └── foo.csv
    └── asd.csv
```

I would like to copy `foo.csv` on same path as I have on source machine to remote machine. So `/test/201512/foo.csv` should be copied to same path `/test/201512/` on remote. If remote machine doesn't have that directory path, it should create it. Does `rsync` or `scp` have any utility to accomplish this ?

(**Note** : Content of `foo.csv` could be different in all directories)

Comment: Have you tried `scp -r` ?

Comment: If you want to copy arbitrarily deep file paths exactly but without copying all parent directories and their contents, you might have an easier time using `tar` and then untarring at the other end.

Comment: @Wildcard could you help me with syntax ?

Comment: @Rahul, actually `rsync` is perfectly fine for this; I hadn't delved into it before to realize it has these options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup, done on my Vagrant box:

```
$ mkdir -p test/20{1512,16{01..12}}
$ for d in !$; do printf 'I am a csv file in %s\n' "$d" > "$d"/foo.csv; printf 'I am a different file; do not copy me!\n' > "$d"/abc.csv; done
```

Directory structure after setup:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ tree test
test
├── 201512
│   ├── abc.csv
│   └── foo.csv
├── 201601
│   ├── abc.csv
│   └── foo.csv
├── 201602
│   ├── abc.csv
│   └── foo.csv
├── 201603
│   ├── abc.csv
│   └── foo.csv
├── 201604
│   ├── abc.csv
│   └── foo.csv
├── 201605
│   ├── abc.csv
│   └── foo.csv
├── 201606
│   ├── abc.csv
│   └── foo.csv
├── 201607
│   ├── abc.csv
│   └── foo.csv
├── 201608
│   ├── abc.csv
│   └── foo.csv
├── 201609
│   ├── abc.csv
│   └── foo.csv
├── 201610
│   ├── abc.csv
│   └── foo.csv
├── 201611
│   ├── abc.csv
│   └── foo.csv
└── 201612
    ├── abc.csv
    └── foo.csv

13 directories, 26 files
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ cat test/201609/foo.csv 
I am a csv file in test/201609
[vagrant@localhost ~]$
```

Next, from my own box (not the vagrant box):

```
rsync -ame 'ssh -p 2222' -f '+ */' -f '+ foo.csv' -f '- *' vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/vagrant/test .
```

Result:

```
$ find test
test
test/201512
test/201512/foo.csv
test/201601
test/201601/foo.csv
test/201602
test/201602/foo.csv
test/201603
test/201603/foo.csv
test/201604
test/201604/foo.csv
test/201605
test/201605/foo.csv
test/201606
test/201606/foo.csv
test/201607
test/201607/foo.csv
test/201608
test/201608/foo.csv
test/201609
test/201609/foo.csv
test/201610
test/201610/foo.csv
test/201611
test/201611/foo.csv
test/201612
test/201612/foo.csv
```

---

**Notes on `rsync` options:**

Here again is the command used:

```
rsync -ame 'ssh -p 2222' -f '+ */' -f '+ foo.csv' -f '- *' vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/vagrant/test .
```

`-a` is the "archive" switch, meaning the directory is copied recursively, permissions are preserved, etc.

`-m` means any empty directories will not be copied (e.g. if one of the date directories is missing `foo.csv` we don't create that directory).

`-e 'ssh -p 2222'` is just because I'm using a Vagrant box which has SSH on a different port than 22; you can omit this part.

`-f` introduces "filter" rules.  You can include or exclude files.  The filters I've used should be fairly self-explanatory—but to clarify the `'+ */'` filter, we need to include all directories so that the `foo.csv` files will be *reached*.

Read more about this in the man page at:

```
LESS='+/INCLUDE\/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES' man rsync
```